# Tailwind CSS is not loading after signin using next auth ( next.js app dir )

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

This is my next auth options :

```
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import { type AuthOptions } from "next-auth";

export const nextAuthOptions: AuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
    name: "Credentials",

    credentials: {
      username: { label: "Username", type: "text", placeholder: "jsmith" },
      password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
   },
    async authorize(credentials: any, req): Promise<any> {
    const user = {
      name: credentials.email,
      id: Math.random(),
      email: credentials.email,
      password: credentials.PhoneOtp,
    };

    if (user) {
      return user;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  },
   }),
 ],
 callbacks: {
   async signIn() {
  return true;
   },
   async jwt({ token, user, trigger, session }: any) {
     if (trigger === "update") {
      return { ...token, ...session.user };
    }

    return { ...token, ...user };
  } ,

  async session({ session, token }: any) {
  session.user = token;
  return session;
},
},
  session: {
  maxAge: 60 * 60, // 1 hour in seconds
  strategy: "jwt",
},
 pages: {
  signIn: "/signin", // Custom sign-in screen URL
},
```

};

And this is my Next middleware file:

```
export { default } from "next-auth/middleware";
export const config = {
 matcher: ["/posts", "/home"],
 };
```

and inside a client component i'm doing sign in like this :

```
    await signIn("credentials", {
      email: userInfo.email,
      password: watch("Phone_otp"),
      redirect: true,
      // accessToken: JSON.stringify(data.response),
      callbackUrl: "/home",
    })
      .then(() => {
        dispatch({
          type: reducerActions.HIDE_LOADER,
        });
        router.push("/home");
        console.log("then executed >");
        // redirect("/home");
      })
      .catch((err: any) => {
        dispatch({
          type: reducerActions.HIDE_LOADER,
        });
        console.log(" signin err > ", err);
      });
```

but after signin the tailwind css is not getting loaded even after doing a hard reload but when sometime i got to unauthorized page and came back then the css is loaded . I have no idea why this behaviour is happened in my next js app.

Answer (score 0):

I had CSS not loading issues with nextjs, nextauth and app router. It turns out because I had the wrong config in `tailwind.config.js`.

My problem came because I initialised the nextjs project without the `src` dir but then I added it retrospectively, and neglecting to update the `tailwind.config.js` messed up the CSS.

Before:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
  ],
  ...
}
```

After:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './src/app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
  ],
  ...
}
```